# Characterization of irreducible multivariate polynomials over the complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains, multivariate-polynomial

Let $\mathbb{C}[X_1,...,X_d]$ denote the set of polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$ in $d$ variables. If $d=1$, we know that the irreducible polynomials are exactly the polynomials of degree $1$, i.e. linear polynomials. Is there any similar characterization of the irreducible polynomials of $\mathbb{C}[X_1,...,X_d]$?

It seems to be a bit harder, since for example the polynomial $X_1^2 + X_2^2$ should also be irreducible.

Comment: It is, indeed, much harder. Your question can more or less be reformulated as "what is the classification of irreducible algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ ?", and such a complete classification would earn you three or four Fields medals.

Comment: I think $x^2+y^2$ is only irreducible in $K[x,y]$ when $K$ doesn't contain an element $a$ such that $a^2=-1$, since otherwise we have $(x-ay)(x+ay)= x^2 -a^2y^2 = x^2+y^2$, so over $\Bbb{C}$ it does reduce. Also I'm not sure one could expect such a characterisation - I remember being surprised how hard it is to classify automorphisms of $k[x,y]$.

Comment: @CaptainLama so then there is also no convenient way to factorize elements of $\mathbb{C}[X_1,...,x_d]$, am I right?

Comment: This is a completely different question. Consider the arithmetic analogue: anyone can easily implement an algorithm to check if a number is prime, and to decompose a number into prime components (maybe not in an optimal way, but still). On the other hand, no one can answer the question "what do prime numbers look like?".